# How to Ignore Certain Fields in unit tests, Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hsqldb

I have the following field in my entity model.

```
@Column(name="key")
@ColumnTransformer(
        read="AES_DECRYPT(key, SHA1('passcode'))", 
        write="AES_ENCRYPT(?, SHA1('passcode'))")
private String secret_key;
```

I am using MySql database and hibernate will perfectly encrypt/decrypt the key value with AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT function. However, the spring embedded databases (HSQL or H2) doesn't know about this specific MySql functions. It throws the following error:

```
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.xxx.Table]
    at ...

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not insert: [com.xxx.Table]
    at ...

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: AES_ENCRYPT
```

So my question is,

1. How can I tell hibernate to ignore this field from writing in certain databases. OR
2. How can I get HSQL and/or H2 work with this mysql function.

Thank you

Comment: For first solution, why do you want ignore this field from writing ? You cannot only Ignore this field in assertion  ? Can you give more details in your question about what you want to test.

Comment: @davidxxx I want to ignore that field because when hibernate tries to insert into the table, it will throw an exception due to incompatibility of functions (which basically doesn't exist in HSQL). I updated the question with the stack trace

Answer (score 2):

add this class to your test config:

```
@Component
public class RemoveAesFunction {



    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        setKey(MyEntity.class);
    }

    private void setKey(Class<?> clazz) {
        try {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("firstName");

            ColumnTransformer columnTransformer = field.getDeclaredAnnotation(ColumnTransformer.class);
            updateAnnotationValue(columnTransformer, "read","");
            updateAnnotationValue(columnTransformer, "write","?");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void updateAnnotationValue(Annotation annotation, String annotationProperty,String value) {
        Object handler = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(annotation);
        Field merberValuesField;
        try {
            merberValuesField = handler.getClass().getDeclaredField("memberValues");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        merberValuesField.setAccessible(true);
        Map<String, Object> memberValues;
        try {
            memberValues = (Map<String, Object>) merberValuesField.get(handler);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        memberValues.put(annotationProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a strong coupling between your entity class and your dbms functions.
Here, the big problem is that the coupling is on metadata that you cannot easily disable at runtime. Therefore, to write some unit-tests, it will encourage you to use bytecode modification at runtime to have what you want. But it brings complexity and potential side-effects in your unit-test.
Besides, a code should be naturaly testable as much as possible( just a remark : with a TDD approach, this kind of problem may be fast noticed and handled).

So, if you can modify the code, I think that a better idea would be to separate the encryption/decryption matter from the domain matter in a way where you could choose implementation you wish for encryption/decryption matter.
In this way, in the applicative scope, you could use the real implementation and 
in unit testing you could use a fake implementation which does nothing or even better no implementation at all.
Hibernate provides Entity Listener mechanisms. With them, you can have hooks at some time of the entity life-cycle.

Here you find more information :
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html

These callbacks could interest you :

> @PrePersist   Executed before the entity manager persist operation is
>   actually executed or cascaded. This call is synchronous with the
>   persist operation.

to encrypt value.

> @PostLoad Executed after an entity has been loaded into the current
>   persistence context or an entity has been refreshed.

to decrypt value.

Finally, you could have two configuration files for hibernate, one with listener  and another one without listener for your unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

With HSQLDB, you can create those functions for test purposes.

```
CREATE FUNCTION AES_DECRYPT(VAL VARCHAR(32000), KEY VARCHAR(32000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(32000) RETURN VAL;

CREATE FUNCTION AES_ENCRYPT(VAL VARCHAR(32000), KEY VARCHAR(32000)) RETURNS VARCHAR(32000) RETURN VAL;
```